# I want to join 2 arrays with a standard usable

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7, array-merge

I have array1

```
array1(
  'orange' => 'orange'
  'banana' => 'banana'
);
```

and array2

```
array2(
    0 => 'apple'
    1 => 'watermellon'
    2 => 'orange'
    3 => 'potatoes'
    4 => 'lemon'
    5 => 'banana'
)
```

and i want to take as reply

```
array3(
    2 => 'orange'
    5 => 'banana'
)
```

I need a real help here!!

Comment: It's not clear to me what should happen to create the output array 3. Do you want to filter array2 based on the values from array1 or something else? Please explain some more.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use array_intersect():

```
$array3 = array_intersect($array2, $array1);
```

Comment: This is working for me. Can you show print_r() for both `$array2` and `$array1`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicer way to do that, but this do the job:

```
$array3 = array();
foreach($array1 as $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $array2)) {
        $array3[array_search($value, $array2)] = $value;
    }
}
```